# Custom ribbon action (office 365)

Tags: calendar, ribbon, office-365, custom-action

I've created a custom list and added on that list a custom action in the ribbon.
Before I created a calendar view on this list, I could see the button in the ribbon, now I can't. Does anyone know what I need to change to see the button in the ribbon again?

Maybe the registrationid is different?

This code was working while I didn't have the new view:

```
    <CustomAction
   Id="ComposeEmailButton"
   Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
   RegistrationId="100"
   RegistrationType="List"
   Sequence="5"
   Title="Compose an Email">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
         Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Share.Controls._children">
          <Button
           Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Share.Controls.ComposeEmail"
           Alt="Compose an Email"
           Command="ComposeEmail"
           Image16by16="/_layouts/images/SENDTO.GIF"
           Image32by32="/_layouts/images/centraladmin_systemsettings_email_32x32.png"
           LabelText="Compose an e-mail"
           TemplateAlias="o1"
           Sequence="30" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler 
          Command="ComposeEmail" 
          CommandAction="javascript:..."
          />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it... I redeployed, reactivated the features and it worked.
No idea why it didn't work ...